# How to add template in Custom Variable HTML Value in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, custom-variable

I have created a custom variable in magento. But I want to call a template file for this variable value.

For this I am using

`{{block type="core/template" template="custom/my.phtml"}}`

in **Variable HTML Value** field.

But when adding this variable in any email template like `{{customVar code=my_var}}` then print

`{{block type="core/template" template="custom/my.phtml"}}`

as it is.

How to add a template file in custom variable HTML value?

Answer (score 3):

you can add your `phtml` file in `email template` simple add the like this and add your coding in `template.phtml`.

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='my/template.phml'}}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working in my case but without `area='frontend'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Custom variables are designed to be used the other way around: you can output the value of a custom variable in your templates. They are not parsed in any way.

If you want to output a template file in another template, you could do two things:

1. Add it in your layout xml as a child block, give it an alias (let's say 'demoblock') and then output it in your original template as `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('demoblock'); ?>`
2. Dynamically create a block and display it's output: `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('theme/my.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>`

Comment: I want to add voucher code with customer new account email, for this I have created a custom variable, but need to add some php code, so I wants to add template file.

Comment: In that case, you can better add a widget or whitelist a block (in System » Permissions » Blocks) and use it in your email like `{{block type="core/template" template="my/template.phtml"}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that through `layout` in your email template.

Step 1: add this `{{layout handle="customer_email_template_custom"}}` in your email template.

Step 2: Add handle in your theme *local.xml*.

```
<customer_email_template_custom>
        <block type="core/template" name="my.custom" template="my/template.phml"/>
</customer_email_template_custom>
```

then you can add your php code in that phtml file.

I have refer order_new email template.

Comment: welcome back :-)

Comment: It is not working for me.